# type 'RenderSliverList' is not a subtype of type 'RenderBox' in type cast - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Hi guys i want to implement flutter popover plugin i just copied the code and paste into my project as given in popover plugin link

https://pub.dev/packages/popover

but i got this error when i click the popover function

**type 'RenderSliverList' is not a subtype of type 'RenderBox' in type cast**

in debugMode it show error line is

```
final box = widget.context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using the `context` of a `RenderSliverList` (most certainly something like `SliverListDelegate` context).

The issue is that this context is *inside* a scrolling view, so it's render object is not a `RenderBox` but a `RenderSliver`.

This is important because they don't use the same constraints, which is what you want here.

The solution is to use a different context, use the one of your `build` method for example and it should work.

Comment: I cant understand how to use different context ,can you please give any short example i used the same code from here https://pub.dev/packages/popover ,

Comment: If you share the part of your code which is not working I can help you, otherwise I'm afraid I don't have time to dig up in a package source code

Comment: Completely accurate answer. The guy who asked should've marked your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to change the findRenderObject() to findAncestorRenderObjectOfType().

This fixed my problem. Using findAncestorRenderObjectOfType() allowed me to find the nearest ancestor of the correct type, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems related to the other Stack Overflow question which is also about using the flutter popover package. I have an answer for it and I am referring people to look at the answer here:

[Type 'RenderSliverList' is not a subtype of type 'RenderBox' in type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498162/type-rendersliverlist-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-renderbox-in-type-cast/75585798#75585798)

Basically you need to wrap the triggering widget ( button/textbutton/iconbutton etc.) into a class so the widget's context will be used by the popover menu items to make the popover appears at the click point of the trigger button (widget).