# Type 'RenderSliverList' is not a subtype of type 'RenderBox' in type cast

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to implement flutter popover plugin, so I just copied and paste the example code given in [popover plugin link](https://pub.dev/packages/popover), but i got this error when i click the popover:

```
Type 'RenderSilverList' is not a subtype of 'RenderBox' in type cast.
```

Here below there is my code:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: createStandardAppBar(title: "Articoli"),
  body: Flex(
    direction: Axis.vertical,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 99,
              bottom: 75,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _loadedItems.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          
                        });
                      },
                      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        child: Container(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 5),
                            child: Row(
                              //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 2,
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(_loadedItems[index]['id'], style: TextStyle(color: headerInfoColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),),
                                      SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                      Text(_loadedItems[index]['descr'], maxLines: 2, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),),                                 
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("€60,00")                                   
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: _loadedItems[index]['iFlagTaglieColori'] == 0 ?
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(child: IconButton(onPressed: () => {}, icon: Icon(Icons.remove, color: Colors.black45, size: 15,), padding:EdgeInsets.zero,),),
                                        GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: (){
                                            showPopover(
                                              context: context,
                                              transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                                              bodyBuilder: (context) => const ListItems(),
                                              onPop: () => print('Popover was popped!'),
                                              direction: PopoverDirection.left,
                                              width: 200,
                                              height: 400,
                                              arrowHeight: 15,
                                              arrowWidth: 30,
                                            );
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                            child: Text("10"),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[400]!),
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(child: IconButton(onPressed: () => {}, icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black45, size: 15,), padding:EdgeInsets.zero,),),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  :
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Text("Taglie/Colori", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 12,),),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    )
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFFE7E7E7), width: 0.5),
                          )
                        ),
                      )
                    );
                  }
                ),  
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 48,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 17, horizontal: 5),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Text("Descrizione", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Text("Prezzo", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Text("Quantita", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[350]
                ),
              ),
            ),
            AnimatedPositioned(
              top: _dropDownOpened ? 48 : -3,
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 5),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 2),
                                  child: Stack(
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: AnimatedOpacity(
                                              opacity: _searchModeSelection == 1 ? 1 : 0,
                                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                                              child: Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: AnimatedOpacity(
                                              opacity: _searchModeSelection == 2 ? 1 : 0,
                                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                                              child: Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: IconButton(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  _searchModeSelection = 1;
                                                });
                                              }, 
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: _searchModeSelection == 1 ? Colors.white : Colors.black45)
                                            )
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: IconButton(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  _searchModeSelection = 2;
                                                });
                                              }, 
                                              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.barcode, color: _searchModeSelection == 2 ? Colors.white : Colors.black45,)
                                            )
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 5),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 2),
                                  child: Stack(
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: AnimatedOpacity(
                                              opacity: _itemsViewSelection == 1 ? 1 : 0,
                                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                                              child: Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: AnimatedOpacity(
                                              opacity: _itemsViewSelection == 2 ? 1 : 0,
                                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                                              child: Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: AnimatedOpacity(
                                              opacity: _itemsViewSelection == 3 ? 1 : 0,
                                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                                              child: Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: AnimatedOpacity(
                                              opacity: _itemsViewSelection == 4 ? 1 : 0,
                                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                                              child: Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: IconButton(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  _itemsViewSelection = 1;
                                                });
                                              }, 
                                              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.list_dash, color: _itemsViewSelection == 1 ? Colors.white : Colors.black45)
                                            )
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: IconButton(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  _itemsViewSelection = 2;
                                                  _futuremisc = _getItems(_itemsViewSelection);
                                                });
                                              }, 
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.local_shipping_outlined, color: _itemsViewSelection == 2 ? Colors.white : Colors.black45,)
                                            )
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: IconButton(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  _itemsViewSelection = 3;
                                                });
                                              }, 
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.history_outlined, color: _itemsViewSelection == 3 ? Colors.white : Colors.black45,)
                                            )
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: IconButton(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  _itemsViewSelection = 4;
                                                });
                                              }, 
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.local_grocery_store_outlined, color: _itemsViewSelection == 4 ? Colors.white : Colors.black45,)
                                            )
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[350]
                )
              ), 
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200)
            ),
            Material(
              elevation: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: Color(0XFFFCFCFC),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 5, 0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 300,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.search, size: 20, color: Colors.blue,),
                            SizedBox(width: 5,),
                            Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: _controller,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.search, 
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: genericHintColor),
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                ),
                                onChanged: _onSearchTextChanged,
                              ),
                            ),
                            if(_currentSearch.length != 0)
                              IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _controller.clear();
                                  _onSearchTextChanged('');
                                }, 
                                icon: Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined, size: 20, color: Colors.blue)
                              )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(onPressed: () => {}, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code_scanner_outlined, color: Colors.blue, size: 20,)),
                          IconButton(onPressed: () => {}, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.blue, size: 20,)),
                          IconButton(onPressed: () => {}, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, icon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined, color: Colors.blue, size: 20,)),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _dropDownOpened = !_dropDownOpened;
                              });
                            }, 
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero, 
                            icon: Icon(
                              _dropDownOpened ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up_rounded : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded, 
                              color: Colors.blue, 
                              size: 20,
                            )
                          )                                        
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                height: 75,
                child: Column(
                  children: [],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
);
```

The `showPopover` method throw an Exception when reached this line of code:

`final box = widget.context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;`

I'm stuck and I don't know where to search. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself. When I searched through the internet, there were not enough answers to the particular issue when using showPopver flutter package.

This problem is a little peculiar because of the way the package acquires widget coordinates. *One has to wrap the button (icon button  or other types of button) that triggers the popup into a class so its own context is used independent of the context of the enclosing widget that has the button.* To solve your exact issue, you can just wrap the gesture detector in your code into a stateless widget class as bellow:

```
class MyPopoverButton extends StatelessWidget {
// add constructor and parameters here to make the code complete...
@override
Widget build(BuilderContext context) {
return
                  GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: (){
                                            showPopover(
                                              context: context,
                                              transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                                              bodyBuilder: (context) => const ListItems(),
                                              onPop: () => print('Popover was popped!'),
                                              direction: PopoverDirection.left,
                                              width: 200,
                                              height: 400,
                                              arrowHeight: 15,
                                              arrowWidth: 30,
                                            );
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                            child: Text("10"),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[400]!),
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
    }
}
```

The theory behind this is that the popover is expecting a render box ancestor, and warping the button that triggers the popover into a class, the button's own builder context will satisfy the requirements.

Give it a try if anyone else runs into the same issue.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just use this.context in popover

```
showPopover(
  context: this.context,
  transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
  bodyBuilder: (context) => const ListItems(),
  onPop: () => print('Popover was popped!'),
  direction: PopoverDirection.top,
  width: 200,
  height: 400,
  arrowHeight: 15,
  arrowWidth: 30,
);
```

Comment: the magic in "this."  you saved my day, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the following components for each element of the list, you can obtain information such as the location of each element

```
Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
      onPressed: () {
        // 通过 Builder 组件来获取 context
        RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
        var offset = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      },
    );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change the `findRenderObject()` to `findAncestorRenderObjectOfType()`.

This fixed my problem. Using findAncestorRenderObjectOfType() allowed me to find the nearest ancestor of the correct type, which solved the problem.